# Provider value returns null

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, provider, flutter-provider

I have a provider:

```dart
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:our_voice/modules/user.dart';
import 'package:our_voice/services/auth.dart';

class UserProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  User? _user;

  User? get user => _user;

  String userid = Auth().currentUser!.uid;

  Future<void> fetchUser() async {
    final snapshot =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(userid).get();
    _user = User.fromFirestore(snapshot);
    notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

and in the MainPage, I want to build a floating action button based on a value named "pending" in the user module

here's the code i'm using:

```dart
return SafeArea(
      child: Consumer<UserProvider>(builder: (context, provider, child) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: _child,
          floatingActionButton: provider.user != null
              ? provider.user!.pending == false
                  ? FloatingActionButton(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
                      onPressed: () {
                        // Navigator.pushNamed(context, QRViewExample.id);
                      },
                      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(50.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: const Icon(
                        Icons.add,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    )
                  : SpeedDial(
                      icon: Icons.menu,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
                      foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                      overlayColor: Colors.transparent,
                      elevation: 20,
                      overlayOpacity: 0.4,
                      direction: SpeedDialDirection.up,
                      spaceBetweenChildren: 5,
                      animatedIcon: AnimatedIcons.menu_close,
                      children: [
                        SpeedDialChild(
                          onTap: () {
                            // Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                            //   // builder: (context) => const QRViewExample(),
                            // ));
                          },
                          elevation: 20,
                          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF018786),
                          child: const Icon(Icons.qr_code),
                          label: 'Scan QR code',
                        ),
                        SpeedDialChild(
                          onTap: () {
                            // Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/canvas');
                          },
                          elevation: 20,
                          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF03DAC6),
                          child: const Icon(Icons.add_photo_alternate),
                          label: 'Add a new art piece',
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
              : Container(),
          floatingActionButtonLocation:
              FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
          bottomNavigationBar: AnimatedBottomNavigationBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            activeColor: Colors.indigo,
            inactiveColor: Colors.black38,
            height: 60,
            icons: iconList,
            activeIndex: _bottomNavIndex,
            gapLocation: GapLocation.center,
            notchSmoothness: NotchSmoothness.softEdge,
            onTap: (value) {
              _getCurrentpage(value);
            },
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
```

when I login for the first time it works. then if I logout and login with another account where the "pending" is true the UI doesn't change based on that value

Comment: hi, do you dispose  UserProvider when you log out? I am trying to check if the data is being cleared or overwritten with the new user.

Comment: when logging out i only logout the current firebase user. i dont dispose the userprovider? is that the problem? if yes how do i fix it?